# Monit start without sudo on starting unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, unicorn, monit

I am using monit at production server. I have installed rbenv and bundler in a user which is in sudo group. Monit is unable to start unicorn server because it uses sudo by default and bundle command is not present in sudo.

```
`$ /etc/init.d/unicorn_demo_app start`
```

is working fine. When I say

```
`$ sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_demo_app start`
```

Giving error as *su: bundle command not found*.
So monit using sudo to start the unicorn server. How can I make Monit NOT TO use `sudo`.?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall rbenv and bundler with standard user?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I dint tried reinstall. But I red using bundler with sudo is not a optimal solution. Is there any way from monit side to make start program without sudo..?

Answer (score 0):

binstubs will solve your problem.  the rbenv docs go into it pretty well https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

Comment: Let me try with this approach.. Thanks